# JTable cell listener JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Need some help to help me understand about jtable cell listeners.

My problem is that i need to catch a change in cell, when it catches, i need to get old value and new value.

The reason i'm asking is that i'm using JTable with DefaultTableModel.

I saw other posts about this, but when i'm trying to implement i do not get any "String" results, only serialized results.

Here is what i'm using:

```
        table.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

            System.out.println(evt.getOldValue());
            System.out.println(evt.getNewValue());
        }

    });
```

this is what i get:

```
null
javax.swing.JTable$GenericEditor@4b20aa93
javax.swing.JTable$GenericEditor@4b20aa93
null
null
javax.swing.JTable$GenericEditor@4b20aa93
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=255,g=255,b=255]
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=0,g=0,b=0]
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=9,g=80,b=208]
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=202,g=202,b=202]
null
false
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=0,g=0,b=0]
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=255,g=255,b=255]
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=202,g=202,b=202]
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=9,g=80,b=208]
false
true
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=255,g=255,b=255]
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=0,g=0,b=0]
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=9,g=80,b=208]
com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=202,g=202,b=202]
true
false
```

Comment: So, what you really should be doing is overriding the `setValueAt` method of the `DefaultTableModel`, this will tell you when a value is been changed and give you access to both the new and old values. You could try using a `TableModelListener`, but then you'd only get the new value

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean by overiding? To create my own method with Overide annotation?

Comment: ... You understand basic OO don't you?  `DefaultTableModel` has a method (inherited from `AbstractTableModel` implanted via `TableModel`) called `setValueAt`, this is (normally) called when some party wants to change a value at a given cell. This would be about the only (reasonable) place for to get both the old and new values

Comment: For clarification, I mean you extend the `DefaultTableModel` and override it's `setValueAt` method and put in your own logic to handle the requirements you have

Comment: @MadProgrammer i know what you meant, but i can't get old value of selected cell. I have to take old and new value.

Comment: The new is passed to setValueAt, at that point you can call getValueAt to get the current/old value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches.

The first is to customize the `TableModel` and override the `setValueAt(...)` method. The basic code would be:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object newValue, int row, int column)
{
    Object oldValue = getValueAt(row, column);

    // do processing with your "oldValue" and the "newValue"

    super.setValueAt(...);
}
```

The other approach is to use a "listener" that you can add to any `TableModel`. For this approach you can the [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/). This class will generate an event whenever the oldValue/newValue has been changed. The event will give you access to both values so you can do your processing.

Depending on your exact requirement you can use either approach.